# How to get time from YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ

Tags: ios, date, swift3, nsdateformatter

Hi I want to get time as `11:40` from `2017-07-31T11:40:00.000Z`

Below is the code I am using:

```
let formatter = Foundation.DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ" //2017-04-01T18:05:00.000
let date1  = formatter.date(from: data.arvTime)
print("date:\(String(describing: date1))")
let dateFormatterPrint = Foundation.DateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let resultTime = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date1!)
print("time:\(String(describing: resultTime))")
```

Getting time as `1:29` i.e. I am getting wrong time.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Add the timezone information of your input string as well in the date formatter.. it should give you right time

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use the dateformat

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

instead of

```
formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ"
```

for full code

```
 let formatter = Foundation.DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" //2017-04-01T18:05:00.000
    let date1  = formatter.date(from: "2017-04-01T18:05:00.000Z")
    print("date:\(String(describing: date1))") 
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let resultTime = formatter.string(from: date1!)
    print("time:\(String(describing: resultTime))")
```

**option-2**

```
    let formatter = Foundation.DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ" //2017-04-01T18:05:00.000
    let date1  = formatter.date(from: "2017-04-01T18:05:00.000Z")
    print("date:\(String(describing: date1))")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let resultTime = formatter.string(from: date1!)
    print("time:\(String(describing: resultTime))")
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: @Karthik Thank you very much

Comment: let string = "2017-01-27T18:36:36Z"
                let formatter = Foundation.DateFormatter()
                   formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
                let date1  = formatter.date(from: string)
                print("date:\(date1!)")
                print(dateFormatter.string(from: date1!))
                formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
                   formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"
                   let resultTime = formatter.string(from: date1!)
                   print("time:\(String(describing: resultTime))")

Comment: date:2017-01-27 18:36:36 +0000
January 28, 2017
time:18:36 PM

Why data is different .. how to get correct date ?

Answer (score 1):

NSLog always prints the date object in GMT timezone, not your local timezone. use your local time zone

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Use the `timeZone` property of the `dateFormatter`.

```
let formatter = Foundation.DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ"
let date1  = formatter.date(from: "2017-07-31T11:40:00.000Z")
print("date:\(String(describing: date1))")
let dateFormatterPrint = Foundation.DateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let resultTime = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date1!)
print("time:\(String(describing: resultTime))")
```

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin  create Extension   you can check it out

The first Step  convert the String to  local Date        here   dateFormat is Your input  data formate      and timeZone is  input Time Zoon

```
fun String.toDate(dateFormat: String = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'", timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UST")): Date? {
val parser = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())
parser.timeZone = timeZone
return parser.parse(this)}
```

Secon Step is to convert  local time into time formate you want    like  : 2022 23 12 10:50:05

```
fun Date.formatTo(dateFormat: String, timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()): String {
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())
formatter.timeZone = timeZone
return formatter.format(this)}
```

Simple call these functions like this

```
fun String.convertToLocalTime():String{
val localFormat="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

this.toDate()?.formatTo(dateFormat = localFormat)?.let {
    return it
}

return ""}
```